How to identify the list of users who is accessing the sharepoint excel file using the office excel web addin (code-type script)
How to identify the list of users who are active in the sharepoint excel file currently using the office excel web addin (code-type script)
identify if we have a user already working on the sharepoint excel and give a warning to the user who opened and loads the addin that this workbook is already in use
